# How do delete a meta key?

Tags: custom-field, pages, meta-query

Unlike the rest of the platform for some reason, there is no apparent way to simply modify a meta key where it lists them for a given page. I created a meta key as a means of testing, but I can't find any option on any component of wordpress that lets me simply append or delete the entire name and its subsequent handles. There is a rollever icon when I roll over the meta key, but no matter how many times I click on it, nothing new loads or attempts to load.

Comment: Why should there be a button on the post editor that deletes data from all other posts? Seems unnecessarily dangerous to me.

Comment: Why would there be a button that automatically assigns data to all other posts? That seems equally dangerous to me.

Comment: It doesn't. Nothing is being saved to other posts.

Comment: That's not what hours of testing says. Every single time I go to any page, it's automatically populated with every meta key. When I tell other elements to filter by a given meta key, it brings up all pages, so yeah, it does.

Answer (score 0):

Metas do not exist on wordpres without handles. Therefore, if you remove all handles from a meta of a given name in your Meta Data Handling section (not accessible from menu without a plugin, rather by adding a new meta key), the key will be automatically deleted.